# How do we toggle on MTP more easily on a Debug-Enabled Android 6.0 device?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

In Android 6.0, [MTP no longer works automatically](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-usb):

> Device connections through the USB port are now set to charge-only mode by default. To access the device and its content over a USB connection, users must explicitly grant permission for such interactions. If your app supports user interactions with the device over a USB port, take into consideration that the interaction must be explicitly enabled.

MTP needs to be re-authorized at least every time you plug in the USB cable, and possibly more frequently than that (timeouts?).

With USB debugging enabled, the only solution that I have found to get MTP sharing to work on the device is to:

- Go into Settings > Developer options
- Scroll down to "Select USB Configuration"
- Switch the value of that option to anything *but* MTP, such as "Charging only" (if it is on MTP right now)
- Switch the value of that option to MTP
- Refresh your MTP client (e.g., on Ubuntu 15.04, close and re-open the window showing the contents of the device)

This is *aggravating* when you are trying to work with a device's files on external storage.

Is there a command-line way to get MTP going, short of writing a UIAutomator "test" that automates the above process? Or, is there some other way to get MTP to work without this sort of prep process?

Comment: Even @CommonsWare asked question on SO.  ;-)

Comment: @DhavalPatel That tells you how annoying a problem this is.  I initially thought it was a bug in Marshmallow.  What a pain.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Marshmallow (6.0 and 6.0.1) it is not possible without some sort of super power :-(

```
adb shell svc usb setFunction mtp
```

throws `java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 2000 nor current process has android.permission.MANAGE_USB.` and `MANAGE_USB` is a `signature|privileged` permission. I filed this as [issue#193062](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193062). It has been put into state *Assigned* and labeled as *Defect-25596495*. It is fixed in N developer preview.

Comment: I've tested on Nexus 5X / NPC56P (i.e. N developer preview #1). It worked.

Comment: On Oreo it reverts after unplugging the cable.